# react useState() not changing the value(an object) in the first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using react usestate() and I want to update `device` state(It is an object)

my problem is when `ShowRelays` component renders for the first time `device` is an empty object and It does not get updated during first rendering, but for the next renders everything is fine

How can I update `device` state for the first time rendering?

(sorry for my bad english)

.

```
function ShowRelays(props) {

const [device, setDevice] = useState({})

let reduxDevices = useSelector(state => state.devicesReducer.devices)

let findDevice = () => {
    let myDevice = reduxDevices.find(x => x._id === props.id)
    setDevice(prevState => {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            ...myDevice
        }
    })
   
}


useEffect(() => {
    if (props.show) {
        findDevice()
    }
}, [props.show])


return
  (
   <div>
    test
   </div>
  )
}
```

`myDevice` object is like:

```
{active: true, name: "device1", id: "deviceId"}
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior, the `useEffect` doesn't run until the component is mounted for the first time, it then fires and populates your state for the second render.

Comment: so how can I execute fincDevice() in the first rendering? Is there any solution for that?

all I want to do is show device info when props.show is true

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to your useState-hook which will calculate your initial value for device.

see [lazy init state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)

```
function ShowRelays(props) {
    let reduxDevices = useSelector(state => state.devicesReducer.devices);
    const [device, setDevice] = useState(() => {
        return reduxDevices.find(x => x._id === props.id)
    });

    return <div>test</div>;
}
```

An other possible solution for your problem without using a separate state could be the following (directly select the right device from your selector function):

```
function ShowRelays(props) {
    const device = useSelector(state => {
        return state.devicesReducer.devices.find(x => x._id === props.id);
    });
    return <div>test</div>;
}
```

Comment: it returns an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
reduxDevice is undefined

Comment: Hmm... are you sure that there are `.devices` in your `state`? I don't have experience with useSelector but I think it should execute synchronously and therefore immediately return the result of your selector function. So the only possible cause of the `TypeError` I can imagine at the moment is, that there are really no devices available? Can you check this?

Comment: I have added a second possible solution in my answer.